# Checking callback != null results in "type List<Pair<String>>) => Null not a subtype of type (List<Pair<dynamic>>) => void"

Tags: flutter

My custom widget uses a callback when it is tapped using a GestureDetector.

The issue is when this widget is clicked, I get the error below:

```
The following _TypeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
type '(List<Pair<String>>) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(List<Pair<dynamic>>) => void'
```

I have ensured so far (to my knowledge) to use the correct type, but it appears somewhere this type isn't detected, however this is confusing as this type check error occurs when performing a null check on a callback.

```
  if (widget.onSelected != null) {   < ---- this line specifically is where the error occurs
    var list = entries.where((element) => element.value).map<Pair<T>>((e) => e.key).toList();
    widget.onSelected(list);
  } else {
    print("null");
  }
```

**Rest of code** (`Pair<T>` and `UiDialogChipSelectorMulti<T>`)

```
class Pair<T> {
  final T value;
  final String label;

  Pair(this.value, this.label);

}

class UiDialogChipSelectorMulti<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Pair<T>> items;
  final Widget label;
  final Widget avatar;
  final List<Pair<T>> initial;
  final ValueChanged<List<Pair<T>>> onSelected;
  final Color onStateOnColor;
  final Color onStateOffColor;

  UiDialogChipSelectorMulti(
      {Key key,
      this.items,
      this.label,
      this.avatar,
      this.onSelected,
      this.initial,
      this.onStateOnColor = Colors.blue,
      this.onStateOffColor = Colors.grey})
      : super(key: key);

      @override
      _UiDialogChipSelectorMultiState createState() =>
          _UiDialogChipSelectorMultiState();
    }
    
 class _UiDialogChipSelectorMultiState<T> extends State<UiDialogChipSelectorMulti> {
      Map<Pair<T>, bool> _selected = {};


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     Widget _buildChip(Pair<T> e) {
     ...

     return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {

          var entries = _selected.entries;

          setState(() {
            if (_selected.containsKey(e)) {
              _selected[e] = !_selected[e];
            } else {
              _selected[e] = true;
            }
          });

          print("Clicked ${e.label} = ${_selected[e]}");

    |->|  if (widget.onSelected != null) {   < ------------------------- Line gets hit, the error is thrown.
            var list = entries.where((element) => element.value).map<Pair<T>>((e) => e.key).toList();
            widget.onSelected(list);
          } else {
            print("null");
          }
        },
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4, right: 4),
          child: Chip(
            label: _buildChipLabel(),
            avatar: _buildChipAvatar(),
            shape: StadiumBorder(
                side: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                  width: 2,
                )),
            backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

**Detailed Log output**:

```
I/flutter (20935): Clicked Young Adults = true

======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
type '(List<Pair<String>>) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(List<Pair<dynamic>>) => void'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _UiDialogChipSelectorMultiState.build._buildChip.<anonymous closure> (package:myawesomeapp/ui/components/ui_dialog_chip_selector_multi.dart:79:22)
#1      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
#2      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:607:11)
#3      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
#4      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:230:7)
...
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#8457e
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: possible
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(127.6, 387.6)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(63.6, 21.9)
  button: 1
  sent tap down
```

Comment: the only "solution" I have (for now) is to remove any trace of generics

Comment: Could you show the type for `_selected`? Looks to me that error occurs specifically at the typecast : `var list = entries.where((element) => element.value).map<Pair<T>>((e) => e.key).toList();`

Comment: @VictorEronmosele updated, I had my types defined there too, *somehow skipped over it not posting it*.

Comment: You're right, the error is from ```if (widget.onSelected != null) { ```. I've added answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the generic to the `State` as well.
So,

```dart
class _UiDialogChipSelectorMultiState<T> extends State<UiDialogChipSelectorMulti>
```

```dart
class _UiDialogChipSelectorMultiState<T> extends State<UiDialogChipSelectorMulti<T>>
```

The error is because the type of the generic could not be inferred from the `widget` property as it just has a type of `UiDialogChipSelectorMulti` while the `widget.onSelected` function requires the type of the generic which it should get from the `widget`.

Saw this solution from this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40825#issuecomment-533493550)

Comment: hmm, can't believe I missed that, thank you!